# Fetch Data from supabase in nuxtjs3

Tags: nuxtjs3, supabase

I get an empty Array when i tried to fetch data from Supabase.

I have everything set up correctly.

The .env file contains the Supabase Url and public key

Here is the script section of the template to fetch the data

````
const client = useSupabaseClient()

const {data: images} = await useAsyncData('images', async () => 
                        await client.from('images')
                        .select('*')
                        .order('created_at')) 

console.log(images.value);

</script>```


As you can see,I tried to log it on the console to see the object but it return an empty array

This is a shot of my database
[![image database of Supabase][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dclYs.png



what am i doing wrong?
````

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't get any data when you have row level security (RLS) turned on and haven't written any policies or your request isn't matching the criteria of the policy. You can disable RLS on the table to see if you get data back first and then you can re-enable it and write a policy that will allow you to get data.